# Validation message doesn't show

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good day everyone! My problem is why the `firstName` & `lastName` error message not showing. The `username` & `password` error message is working fine. Even if the `password` and `confirm password` error is working fine. The only problem is when my `firstName` and `lastName` is empty no error message show. I already download the `jQuery` and include it to my head tag. I double check the id names if same with my html. I think there are same. Can somebody help me regarding to my problem? I will show you my codes below!

```js
$(function() {

  $("#firstname_errors").hide(); //hide the span tag
  $("#lastname_errors").hide(); //hide the span tag

  var error_firstnames = false;
  var error_lastnames = false;

  $("#form_firstnames").focusout(function() {
    check_firstname();
  });

  $("#form_lastnames").focusout(function() {
    check_lastname();
  });

  function check_firstname() {

    var firstname = $("#form_firstnames").val();
    if (firstname == "") {
      $("#firstname_errors").html("Firstname is empty");
      $("#firstname_errors").show();
      $("#firstname_errors").addClass("formError");
      error_firstnames = true;
    } else {
      $("#firstname_errors").hide();
    }
  }

  function check_lastname() {
    var lastname = $("#form_lastnames").val();
    if (lastname == "") {
      $("#lastname_errors").html("Lastname is empty");
      $("#lastname_errors").show();
      $("#lastname_errors").addClass("formError");
      error_lastnames = true;
    } else {
      $("#lastname_errors").hide();
    }
  }

  $("#registration_forms").submit(function() {
    error_firstnames = false;
    error_lastnames = false;
    check_firstname();
    check_lastname();

    if (error_firstname = false && error_lastname = false) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<form id=registration_forms action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
  <div>
    <label for="fname">First Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="form_firstnames" placeholder="First Name" autocomplete="off">
    <span id="firstname_errors"></span> //error message
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="lname">Last Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="lname" id="form_lastnames" placeholder="Last Name" autocomplete="off">
    <span id="lastname_errors"></span> //error message
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="submit" name="btnSave" value="Register">
  </div>
  Already a member? <a href="login.php">Login</a>
</form>
```

Comment: `if (error_firstname = false && error_lastname = false)` you need to use `==` to compare.

Comment: Or just write `if (!error_firstname && !error_lastname)`. It's usually poor style to compare with `true` or `false`.

Comment: Didn't you get a syntax error in the JavaScript console from that line?

Comment: There's also no need for `if/else`, just `return !error_firstname && !error_lastname;`

Comment: @Barmar not working sir

Comment: See the code in my answer, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
if (error_firstname = false && error_lastname = false)
```

It's doing assignment, not comparison. Change that `if/else` to:

```
return !error_firstnames && !error_lastnames;
```

```js
$(function() {

  $("#firstname_errors").hide(); //hide the span tag
  $("#lastname_errors").hide(); //hide the span tag

  var error_firstnames = false;
  var error_lastnames = false;

  $("#form_firstnames").focusout(function() {
    check_firstname();
  });

  $("#form_lastnames").focusout(function() {
    check_lastname();
  });

  function check_firstname() {

    var firstname = $("#form_firstnames").val();
    if (firstname == "") {
      $("#firstname_errors").html("Firstname is empty");
      $("#firstname_errors").show();
      $("#firstname_errors").addClass("formError");
      error_firstnames = true;
    } else {
      $("#firstname_errors").hide();
    }
  }

  function check_lastname() {
    var lastname = $("#form_lastnames").val();
    if (lastname == "") {
      $("#lastname_errors").html("Lastname is empty");
      $("#lastname_errors").show();
      $("#lastname_errors").addClass("formError");
      error_lastnames = true;
    } else {
      $("#lastname_errors").hide();
    }
  }

  $("#registration_forms").submit(function() {
    error_firstnames = false;
    error_lastnames = false;
    check_firstname();
    check_lastname();

    return !error_firstnames && !error_lastnames;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id=registration_forms action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
  <div>
    <label for="fname">First Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="form_firstnames" placeholder="First Name" autocomplete="off">
    <span id="firstname_errors"></span> //error message
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="lname">Last Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="lname" id="form_lastnames" placeholder="Last Name" autocomplete="off">
    <span id="lastname_errors"></span> //error message
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="submit" name="btnSave" value="Register">
  </div>
  Already a member? <a href="login.php">Login</a>
</form>
```